# How do I create a .bash_profile alias for a GroupMe bot's message command

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, groupme

I have a GroupMe bot that can send messages to the chat it is assigned to in this format:

```
curl -d '{"text" : "text", "bot_id" : "(REDACTED)"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post
```

So, instead of typing up this monstrosity every time I wanted to send a message, I decided to create an alias for it.

Here is what I attempted to use in my .bash_profile for this:

```
alias groupmessage=groupmessagefunction
groupmessagefunction() { curl -d '{"text" : $1, "bot_id" : "(REDACTED)"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post; }
```

Could anyone inform me what the correct formatting would be to get this to work? Thanks!

**Update 1:**

I now have my code as follows:

```
v="bot_id_string"
alias groupmessage=groupmessagefunction
groupmessagefunction() { curl -d '{"text" : '"$1"', "bot_id" : '"$v"'}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post; }
```

I would like to point out that what I am trying to accomplish is type in something like:

```
groupmessage "hello"
```

or

```
groupmessage hello
```

Then, it will send out the following command:

```
curl -d '{"text" : "hello", "bot_id" : "bot_id_string"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post
```

I hope this helps clarify this question if any misunderstanding occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I hope this will be the solution for you:

```
v=bot_id
curl -d '{"text" : "Test", "'$v'" : "(REDACTED)"}' api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post
```

You have to use `' '` around `$v` --> `'$v'` because this will allow bash to evaluate `$v` inside `curl -d ' ... '` .

## Answer for your Update 1

As I see it would be the better way to use `eval` command:

```
v="bot_id_string"
alias groupmessage=groupmessagefunction
groupmessagefunction() {
    a="curl -d '{\"text\" : \"$1\", \"bot_id\" :  \"$v\"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post"
    echo "$a"    # this echo just for checking
    eval "$a"; }

groupmessage "Hello is it working now ?"
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for responding. When I run the program, I get: {"meta":{"code":400,"errors":["Invalid bot_id"]},"response":null}~

Comment: However, curl -d '{"text" : "Test", "bot_id" : "(REDACTED)"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post works when I type it on the command line, so I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify it if that helps. The newest solution still does not work, and the same error message occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The same error occurred, and the echo produced curl -d '{text : "Test 2", bot_id :  "eda9e33e92c82775b0a706321f"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post

Comment: The echo doesn't have quotes around the words "text" and "bot_id" for some reason, though.